# Why are we allowed to use these proof techniques in mathematical logic?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

In a well known book I am reading about mathematical logic, in the chapter of propositional calculus, he uses induction and contrapositive proof to prove things **about** propositional calculus. But I am wondering, why is this allowed?

The reason I find this unclear is that contrapositive proof is also formulated inside propositional calculus as $(A\rightarrow B) \leftrightarrow(\neg B\rightarrow \neg A )$. But when he proves things about logic he is not inside the language?

The same way he uses induction. But we also have that induction comes after first-order logic when you create ZFC and create the natural numbers?

So why are we allowed to use these techniques that are inside logic on the language itself? Is not a point of creating logic to formalize these proof techniques?, and hence why does it make sense to use them when they haven yet "been created"?

Comment: [This is very closely related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2379785/25554); if this answers your question, please click on the "close" link and close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: [Another related discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4251587/279914). We formalize logic and proof as mathematical objects so that we can reason *about* them, not as a prerequisite for *using* them. There's no "building logic from scratch" in the sense you're imagining; we necessarily always start with some assumed agreement on what constitutes valid reasoning.